# Unattended silent install of SBT not working

Tags: sbt

Can IU please ask for some help in completing an unsttanded install of SBT.

if Use the following command  - it fails.
msiexec.exe /A "c:\Users\Gavin Baumanis\Downloads\sbt-1.2.8.msi" /PASSIVE REBOOT=N

I also tried;
msiexec.exe /A "c:\Users\Gavin Baumanis\Downloads\sbt-1.2.8.msi" /PASSIVE REBOOT=N AcceptEULA=Yes

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but the install with MSIEXEC is not working.
An unattended install can be achieved by just calling the MSI directly;

"c:\Users\Gavin Baumanis\Downloads\sbt-1.2.8.msi" /qn